# Prove that $E(t)=\int\limits^L_0h^2(x)+(g'(x))^2+(g''(x))^2+(g'''(x))^2dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

Consider  for $L>0$, the initial boundary value problem:
$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_{tt}-u_{xx}+u_{xxxx}-u_{xxxxxx}=0 \text{ in }(0,L)\times(0,T)\\ 
u(x,0)=g(x) \text{ and }u_t(x,0)=h(x)\\
u(0,t)=0, u(L,t)=0, u_{xx}(0,t)=0, u_{xx}(L,t)=0, u_{xxxx}(0,t)=0, u_{xxxx}(L,0)=0
\end{matrix}\right.$

Define $E(t)=\int\limits_0^Lu_t^2(x,t)+u_x^2(x,t)+u^2_{xx}(x,t)+u^2_{xxx}(x,t)dx$
Prove that $E(t)=\int\limits^L_0h^2(x)+(g'(x))^2+(g''(x))^2+(g'''(x))^2dx$

**My attempt:**

Here I'm trying to prove that $\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=0$. Thus $E(t)$ is a constant. So $E(t)=E(0)$ which gives the result. And to show that the derivative is zero,

I first multiplied the equation by $u$ and:
$I=\int\limits_0^Luu_{tt}-uu_{xx}+uu_{xxxx}-uu_{xxxxxx}dx$

Now observe that:

- $\int\limits_0^Luu_{tt}dx=\int\limits_0^L\frac{d}{dt}(uu_t)-(u_t)^2dx$
- $\int\limits_0^Luu_{xx}dx=\int\limits_0^L\frac{d}{dt}(uu_x)-(u_x)^2dx$

And by integration by parts

- $\int\limits_0^Luu_{xxxx}dx=uu_{xxx}|_0^L-\int\limits_0^Lu_{xxx}u_xdx=-\int\limits_0^Lu_{xxx}u_xdx=-(u_{xx})^2|^L_0+\int\limits_0^L(u_{xx})^2dx=\int\limits_0^L(u_{xx})^2dx$

Similarly

- $\int\limits_0^Luu_{xxxxxx}dx=-\int\limits_0^L(u_{xxx})^2dx$

Thus
$I=\int\limits_0^L\frac{d}{dt}(uu_t)-(u_t)^2dx-\int\limits_0^L\frac{d}{dt}(uu_x)+(u_x)^2dx+\int\limits_0^L(u_{xx})^2dx+\int\limits_0^L(u_{xxx})^2dx=0$

But after this I cannot see how to rearrange the terms to obtain the solution.
Appreciate your help..

Comment: Good lord, can you please use $\partial_x^6 u$ instead of $u_{xxxxxx}$?

Comment: Are there no boundary conditions for $u_{xxx}$ and $u_x$?